# Can't print Excel file values

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I need to read an Excel file and record it on my database. I'm using Laravel + [Maatwebsite/Laravel-excel](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import) to Read the file.  With my currently code I get no errors but no data is shown in the browser:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
Use Excel;

class ImportController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        Excel::load('test.xls', function($reader) {
            $result = $reader->get();

            foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                echo $value->situation;
            }


        })->get();   

    }
}
```

*var_dump($result)*

> object(Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\RowCollection)#634 (2) { ["title":protected]=> string(9) "Worksheet" ["items":protected]=> array(161) { [0]=> object(Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\CellCollection)#646 (2) { ["title":protected]=> NULL ["items":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> NULL } } [1](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import)=>

Comment: Have you made a `var_dump` on `result`?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the result via:

```
// Loop through all sheets
$reader->each(function($sheet) {

    // Loop through all rows
    $sheet->each(function($row) {

    });

});
```

On http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import you can find more information.